# Passthrough Password

Tags: passwords, cmd.exe, psexec

I am trying to `psexec` to a remote machine and run a program through a cmd command, however the program prompts for a password (not a windows password).

Is there a way to add this password to the command line?

Currently

```
psexec \\ <remote Computer> -u USER -p Password -e cmd /C Program
```

I have tried putting password at the end but it keeps saying: `Password timed out`.

Comment: Lookup which parameters the program supports. If it doesn't have support to accept input using parameters you might be able to use input redirection. But you've provided very little detail. Currently the information is just used by `psexec` to connect.

Comment: Thanks i will give that ago. Its hard to really say anymore as the process is just to connect run program and enter password. the program is used to put the device into update mode.